# How to lock the android window to not change when the phone is lying down on Android?

Tags: android

How to lock the android window to not change when the phone is  lying down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean how do you prevent rotation in an application, you can configure rotation for each activity in the Application Manifest. If you specify a landscape or portrait orientation for an activity, that activity will be forced into that orientation and will not rotate.